# datatimepicker updating failed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

i receive a message `"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."` when i'm trying to update/insert my database date column with a value from datatimepicker
i used the same datatimepicker to insert/update date and it works for some values not all the dates
what is the problem??
why does it work for some values(like the default one) and doens't work for other values??

my insert code

```
Insert into Courses_tbl (course_date) VALUES('"+datatimepicker1.value+"');
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this:

```
 string chk = "Insert into Courses_tbl (course_date) VALUES('" + datatimepicker1.value + "')";
```

and database feilds datatype change it to varchar(50)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If it works for some values it's like to be a format issue.</strike>

When setting up your datepicker, be sure to select the correct format:

`var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();`

Edit: Sorry, realised you're using C# in which case you want:

`DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`

`DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"`

Or you can select some other format.

Comment: Consider that the `.value` format may be different. You should try doing `datetimepicker1.value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` and putting your formatting string in like that (depending on what's going into your database). The actual correct way to do this is not to use a string, you should use parameterised SQL where you can specify that a parameter is a `DateTime` and it will take care of it for you. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 0):

it may due to database considering date as a month. In your success case date may be less than 12 so db considering it as month. in case date is greater than 12, say 25 then db will throw exception.

you need to specify the date format.

try below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/188662/how-to-insert-date-in-SQL-SERVER-using-C-NET